# Does a React Native project by default uses Javascript or Typescript?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native development so bear with me.

When I create a new React Native project via CMD and I see the code, the .js has a lot of keywords used in TypeScript.

This not seems to be plain Javascript or I'm wrong? What I am seeing is Javascript or Typescript?

Thank you

Comment: React Native is actually having a never-ending battle between Flow (by Facebook) and TypeScript. FB has admitted that TS is a way to go, but still many keeps Flow as their primary type checker.

I've been using both so I don't have optimised opinion which one you should be using.

And this is not a SO related question, so consider elaborating it somehow or accept it to be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question: in the App.js file (of at least > 0.52) you can see the following at the top of the file:

`/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */`

The syntax you see there is [Flow](https://flow.org/) (like React also from Facebook), which is an alternative for Typescript (from Microsoft). Flow and React got a different syntax and are both compatible with React / React Native. Understandably though, Facebook is pushing their own Flow. It is not necessary to use it. It also works with regular javascript.

Answer (score 1):

React native script uses JavaScript by default. Typescript files have .ts extension.

You can also user TypeScript in React Native with certain configuration. Following links will help you for this

[TypeScript React Native Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Native-Starter)

[React-native-with-typescript](https://medium.com/@rintoj/react-native-with-typescript-40355a90a5d7)

Answer (score 1):

By default you are seeing Flowtype.

Flow is great, but Typescript seems to be the direction developers are going.

If you want to use Typescript, try this:

`react-native init MyApp --template typescript`

Also checkout: https://medium.com/@emin93/react-native-typescript-b965059109d3

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript 
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript